# null pointer exception when initializing a null value items

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I want to give value to each of the sub items of a class called State while I have a an array of States initially all null, I am receiving null pointer reference here :

```
//finding all the neighbor states of a given configuration

public State[] neighborStates(String config, int modeFlag){
    State[] neighborStates=new State[7];
    int i=0;
    for (Operation o : Operation.values()){
        neighborStates[i].config=move(config,o.name().charAt(0));
        neighborStates[i].realCost++;
        neighborStates[i].opSequence+=o.name();
        neighborStates[i].heuristicCost=getHeuristicCost(neighborStates[i].config, modeFlag);
        i++;
    }       

    return neighborStates;
}
```

I changed the code to this but I yet get NPE:

```
public State[] neighborStates(String config, int modeFlag){
        State[] neighborStates=new State[8];
        int i=0;
        for (Operation o : Operation.values()){
            neighborStates[i] = new State(move(config,o.name().charAt(0)),neighborStates[i].realCost++,
                                getHeuristicCost(neighborStates[i].config, modeFlag), neighborStates[i].opSequence+=o.name());
            //neighborStates[i].config=move(config,o.name().charAt(0));
            //neighborStates[i].realCost++;
            //neighborStates[i].opSequence+=o.name();
            //neighborStates[i].heuristicCost=getHeuristicCost(neighborStates[i].config, modeFlag);
            i++;
        }
```

class State is defined as:

```
public class State {
    public State(String config, int realCost, int heuristicCost, String opSequence){
        this.config = config;
        this.realCost = realCost;
        this.heuristicCost = heuristicCost;
        this.opSequence = opSequence;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to instantiate `State`(s) in your `neighborStates` array. You have created an array with 7 slots, but they're all initially `null`. Assuming you have a default constructor, it should look something like,

```
for (Operation o : Operation.values()){
  neighborStates[i] = new State();
  // ...
```

Also, it's probably a good idea to size `neighborStates` based on `Operation.values()`

```
State[] neighborStates = new State[Operation.values().length];
```

Comment: Hi Elliot, I updated the code to what you said but I yet get NPE, can you please take a look?

Comment: That isn't what I said, and your `State` went from not constructor to taking everything?

Comment: because the constructor in State.java is like `public State(String config, int realCost, int heuristicCost, String opSequence)`

Comment: What is `move`, you know that `neighborStates[i].realCost++` would just be 1, what is `getHeuristicCost`, and where is the NPE?

Comment: `getHeuristicCost` is still using `neighborStates[i]` in the initialization of `neighborStates[i]`. At that point it will still be null!

Comment: when `neighborStates[i].realCost++ ` is called , NPE happens! Sorry I cannot share more of my code due to privacy

Comment: @MonaJalal I'd suggest creating getter/setter methods for your class if you haven't done so already - that way you can use `neighborStates[i] = new State();`, create methods such as `setConfig(String config) { this.config = config;`, and then retrieve necessary information using `neighborStates[i].getConfig()` or something similar.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the class State.java!

Comment: @MonaJalal We want to help you, but if you can't share any more code I think it's time you learned to use your debugger. What you'll discover is that `neighborStates[i]` is still `null` when you're trying to access `realCost`. As I tried to tell you, it should initially be 0 so you're trying to access a `0` (which isn't `0` yet) and set it to `1`. Just use 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array of a specified size as you do with
`State[] neighborStates = new State[7]` you allocate that memory. Each index of the array is initialized with whatever the default value for the type is. The default value for booleans is `false`. The default value for numbers is `0`. Here's the part that matters: the default value for references is `null`.

All of the values in the array will be null until you instantiate them with, say `neighborState[i] = new State();`

Answer (score 0):

When you write this line of code
    State[] neighborStates=new State[7];
You just receive a refrence to a Array Object, with all of 7 item inside is null, this line only initialize the State Array object, without any items inside.

So in the for loop, all item is still null, you have to initialize each item first befor using it. 
    neighborStates[i] = new State();

Answer (score 0):

For the version of your question **after the update**.

You are evaluating this expression -

```
new State(move(config,o.name().charAt(0)),neighborStates[i].realCost++,
                            getHeuristicCost(neighborStates[i].config, modeFlag), neighborStates[i].opSequence+=o.name());
```

before you have assigned a value to `neighborStates[i]`.  So the part that says `neighborStates[i].realCost++` is triggering the null pointer exception - `neighborStates[i]` is still `null`.

Answer (score -1):

You only init an array , but you have not constructed the member in State[] array.
You need to call constructor to construct the State class before you use it.
Try to change your code like this:

```
public State[] neighborStates(String config, int modeFlag){
    State[] neighborStates=new State[7];
    int i=0;
    for (Operation o : Operation.values()){
        neighborStates[i] = new State(move(config,o.name().charAt(0)),
                                      someRealCost, //what's the value of this parameter?
                                      getHeuristicCost(config, modeFlag),
                                      modeFlag
                                      );
        ....
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no such constructor as State in State.java and I am supposed not to change the class State.java! The only constructor for State in mentioned in the question

Comment: You are right, it should use the unique constructor of State.

Comment: I check your modification in question. you can't use the member of object before it have been construct. Can you provide the logic of realCost? I didn't see any method to get its value.